# SCSS генератор случайного цвета. Запись в переменную?

Tags: sass, случайные-числа, scss

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите, пожалуйста как в SCSS занести сгенерируемые значения цвета в "некую переменную" для последующей работы с ними? Приведу простой пример

```css
.bigBlock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.block, .block2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

$rainbow_segments: 10;
$s-min: 30;
$s-max: 90;
$l-min: 10;
$l-max: 90;
.bigBlock {
  @for $i from 1 through $rainbow_segments {
    .block:nth-child(#{$i})  {
      background-color: hsl(random(360), $s-min+random($s-max+-$s-min), $l-min+random($l-max+-$l-min));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bigBlock">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="bigBlock">
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpBPaR

Как сделать так что б блоки с классом .block2 были на порядок (темнее/светлее) чем блоки над ними с классом .block?
Как получать значения случайного цвета из цикла, что б потом с ним работать?